# A CXmlApiException was raised in native code : error 16 : scxmlapi(16) - Invalid or missing file name in XML request

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am getting below error when Soap Request is called from android application:

> A CXmlApiException was raised in native code : error 16 : scxmlapi(16)
>
> Invalid or missing file name in XML request

Comment: how can i add soap:Body>

<CreateProblemRequest filename="rootcause"

xmlns="http://<server>:<port>/SM/7"> in android application

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the type of action is not recognized, Examples of Actions: Retrieve, Add, Update